# Python 2.6 how to convert this string to dict?

Tags: python, string, python-2.6

```
str = "{ u'source_ip',  u'127.0.0.1'}, { u'db_ip',  u'43.53.696.23'}, { u'db_port',  u'3306'}, { u'user_name',  u'uz,ifls'} "
```

how do I convert this string to dict?

```
"source_ip":"127.0.0.1","db_ip":"43.53.696.23","db_port":"3306"
```

I have tried

```
str = dict(str)
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Is there a formal specification for that string representation? It looks kinda like a modified python 2.x thing.

Comment: If it was something like `{'source_ip':'127.0.0.1`}` you could have used `eval()`

Answer (score 4):

Those fragments look like python sets. If you run them through `ast.literal_eval` you get something close, but since sets are not ordered, you can't guarantee which of the two items is the key and which is the value. This is a total hack, but I replaced the curly braces with parens so they look more tuple-like and made the dictionary from there.

```
>>> mystr = "{ u'source_ip',  u'127.0.0.1'}, { u'db_ip',  u'43.53.696.23'}, { u'db_port',  u'3306'}, { u'user_name',  u'uz,ifls'} "
>>> mystr = mystr.replace('{', '(').replace('}', ')')
>>> import ast
>>> mydict = dict(ast.literal_eval(mystr))
>>> mydict
{u'user_name': u'uz,ifls', u'db_port': u'3306', u'source_ip': u'127.0.0.1', u'db_ip': u'43.53.696.23'}
>>>
```

Comment: Functional and complete - hacky or not, practicality beats purity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to convert your entire input string to a dict or not, because the output you gave confuses me.
Otherwise, my answer will give you an output like the second hilighted text you want in a dict format:

```
a = "{ u'source_ip',  u'127.0.0.1'}, { u'db_ip',  u'43.53.696.23'}, { u'db_port',  u'3306'}, { u'user_name',  u'uz,ifls'} "
c = a.replace("{", '').replace("}","").replace(" u'", '').replace("'", '').replace(" ", "").split(",")
d, j = {}, 0
for i in range(len(c)):
    if j +2 > len(c):
        break
    if c[j] == "user_name":
        #d[c[j]] = "uz,ifls" #uncomment this line to have a complete dict
        continue
    d[c[j]] = c[j+1]
    j += 2
```

Output:

```
print d 
{'db_port': '3306', 'source_ip': '127.0.0.1', 'db_ip': '43.53.696.23'}
print type(d)
<type 'dict'>
```

If you want to have a complete dict of your string uncomment the line which is commented above, and the output will be:

```
print d
{'user_name': 'uz,ifls', 'db_port': '3306', 'source_ip': '127.0.0.1', 'db_ip': '43.53.696.23'}
print type(d)
<type 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- The top-level data structure is actually a tuple (because in Python, `1, 2, 3` is the same as `(1, 2, 3)`.
- As others have pointed out, the inner data structures are set literals, which are not ordered.
- Set literals are implemented in Python 2.6 but not in its `ast.literal_eval` function, which is [arguably a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue10091).
- As it turns out, you can make your own custom `literal_eval` function and make it do what you want.

```
from _ast import *
from ast import *

# This is mostly copied from `ast.py` in your Python source.

def literal_eval(node_or_string):
    """
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts,
    sets, booleans, and None.
    """
    if isinstance(node_or_string, str):
        node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
    if isinstance(node_or_string, Expression):
        node_or_string = node_or_string.body
    def _convert(node):
        if isinstance(node, (Str)):
            return node.s
        elif isinstance(node, Tuple):
            return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, Set):
            # ** This is the interesting change.. when
            # we see a set literal, we return a tuple.
            return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, Dict):
            return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
                        in zip(node.keys, node.values))
        raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
    return _convert(node_or_string)
```

Then we can do:

```
>>> s = "{ u'source_ip',  u'127.0.0.1'}, { u'db_ip',  u'43.53.696.23'}, { u'db_port',  u'3306'}, { u'user_name',  u'uz,ifls'} "
>>> dict(literal_eval(s))
{u'user_name': u'uz,ifls', u'db_port': u'3306', u'source_ip': u'127.0.0.1', u'db_ip': u'43.53.696.23'}
```